# How to process xml file having same xmlnodes scattered over at same levels

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have a big xml file contains many `testObject` nodes, but I have to concentrate only testobject of class type `LNCEL` and `BTSSCL`.

Here `LNCEL` and `BTSSCL` are related with their `distName` attribute; for example first object of `btsId = 12282` has parent `distName` like `PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-12282`, only this part has to be matched with `testobject` of Class `LNCEL` which has distName=`PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-12282`.

In a nutshell I have a lot of objects in this XML file and each object I need values for name attributes `btsId,btsName,mcc,mnc,name` which are scattered over two classes of types `LNCEL` and `BTSSCL`.

Small snippet of xml is as shown here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE am SYSTEM 'am20.dtd'>
<am version="2.0" xmlns="am20.xsd">
  <cmData type="actual">
    <testObject class="BTSSCL" version="FL16A" distName="PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-12282/BTSSCL-1" id="400240">
      <p name="btsId">12282</p>
      <p name="btsName">DT_AR_L_2282_HERITAGEVILLAGEMZDdu</p>
    </testObject>
    <testObject class="LNCEL" version="FL16A" distName="PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-12282/LNBTS-12282/LNCEL-4" id="400243">
      <p name="mcc">424</p>
      <p name="mnc">02</p>
      <p name="name">AR_2282_22824_L2_A </p>
    </testObject>
    <testObject class="LNCEL" version="FL16A" distName="PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-11287/LNBTS-11287/LNCEL-2" id="120446">
      <p name="mcc">424</p>
      <p name="mnc">02</p>
      <p name="name">AO_1287_12872_L1_B</p>
    </testObject>
    <testObject class="BTSSCL" version="FL16A" distName="PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-11287/BTSSCL-1" id="120589">
      <p name="btsId">11287</p>
      <p name="btsName">EF_AO_L_1287_BaniyasWest</p>
    </testObject>
  </cmData>
</am>
```

Comment: Parse the file to XDocument. Then you could query different parts of the structure.

Comment: how to corelate the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            XElement root = doc.Root;
            XNamespace ns = root.GetDefaultNamespace();

            List<XElement> testObject = root.Descendants(ns + "testObject").Where(x => ((string)x.Attribute("class") == "BTSSCL") || ((string)x.Attribute("class") == "LNCEL")).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: plus i used your old logic also:)

Comment: I didn't realize if was you peter.  I do usually look at name of people who post because the name is at the bottom of posting.  The response a much shorted and the names are more obvious.  When I know the person posted a previous request I usually go back and review the older request.